# Can I pass a class to be used with css in a .json object?

Tags: javascript, css, json, angularjs

I have a .json object that's then displayed through Angular by ng-bind:

```
<p ng-bind-html="paragraph" ng-repeat="paragraph in content.sections[0].pages[1].paragraphs"></p>
```

The .json has this structure:

```
{
  "header":"A",
  "url":"#/us/en/a/b/c/c",
  "paragraphs":[
    "Something something <a class='plink' href='http://blahblah.com' target='_blank'>blah blah</a>."
  ]
}
```

The code is pulled through but the class is dropped. No errors in console.

How do I append class to that link?

Comment: Try adding double quote in html attribute and single quote in string property value

Comment: Not quite but you got me on a right path!

Answer (score 0):

Just need to use double quotes with an escape character.

Like this:

```
{
  "header":"A",
  "url":"#/us/en/a/b/c/c",
  "paragraphs":[
    "Something something <a class=\"plink\" href='http://blahblah.com' target='_blank'>blah blah</a>."
  ]
}
```